# 'rxjs' module not found while running Jest test suite

Tags: jestjs, rxjs, nestjs

I have a Nest JS application for which I am writing tests for some of the Provider classes. The beforeAll fn. of jest defined in my *.spec.ts file runs fine but the jest todo() fn. fails with the following error:

```
    Cannot find module 'rxjs' from 'node_modules/@nestjs/common/cache/interceptors/cache.interceptor.js'

    Require stack:
      node_modules/@nestjs/common/cache/interceptors/cache.interceptor.js
      node_modules/@nestjs/common/cache/interceptors/index.js
      node_modules/@nestjs/common/cache/index.js
      node_modules/@nestjs/common/index.js
      node_modules/@nestjs/testing/testing-module.builder.js
      node_modules/@nestjs/testing/test.js
      node_modules/@nestjs/testing/index.js
      src/bookmark/test/integration/bkm.service.int-spec.ts

      at Resolver._throwModNotFoundError (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/resolver.js:491:11)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@nestjs/common/cache/interceptors/cache.interceptor.js:5:16)
```

My package.json has rxjs defined in the "dependencies" section with a version of ^7.2.0.

My test in the *.spec.ts testing class looks like this:

```
describe('BookmarkService Integration', () => {
    let prisma: PrismaService;
    let bookmarkService: BookmarkService
    beforeAll(async () => {
        const moduleRef = await Test.createTestingModule({
          imports: [AppModule],
        }).compile();
    
        prisma = moduleRef.get(PrismaService);
        bookmarkService = moduleRef.get(BookmarkService);
        await prisma.cleanDatabase();
      });
    it.todo('Default test pass')
})
```

I have not tried explicitly doing a npm install of rxjs since I don't understand the consequence of installing it when it already came as a default dependency when I initialized my Nest application. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you try to remove the ```node_modules``` directory and the ```package-lock.json``` file, then doing ```npm install```

Comment: That worked like a charm! Pardon my lack of understanding of package-lock.json but I tried to compare the rxjs dependency versions in the old package-lock.json and the new one and could not find any obvious difference. May I ask what exactly made it work?

Comment: That's good to hear! I have added my explanation in the answer below :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Cannot find module` is a common error that is thrown when a dependency requested by your project code or by one of the imported modules cannot find the target module inside the `node_module` directory.

This issue can be caused by a multitude of scenarios, but going by your response to my comment, it was likely caused by the fact that `npm` had cached the `package-lock.json` properties and upon rerunning `npm install` would still add incorrect modules to the `node_modules` directory. Hence the **resolution** is a simple deletion of the `node_modules` directory, the `package-lock.json` file and the rerunning of the `npm install` command.

To answer your question on how this was still a problem even when `package-lock.json` did contain the `rxjs` library reference, there could have been a number of scenarios that I would have to speculate; for one, what you were inspecting could have been a *transitive* `rxjs` dependency which is being used by another library and is not the `rxjs` library that is actually being requested for in the error. Alternatively, there is a chance that even though `rxjs` was defined in the `package-lock.json` file, it may not have actually been present in the `node_modules` directory as it may have failed to install. This really depends on the exact sequence of things that you have done prior to seeing the issue, but I hope my explanation clarifies the problem you were facing.